# Calculating the mean in a multilvel column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

It consist of multiple level columns. The level `disease_state` describes the disease state (control or sporadic_PD) and each number corresponds to the biological replicate. Each replicate consists of a triplicate. From that triplicate I want to calculate the mean within each triplicate (indicated by red bubble) and use the columns in `disease_state_general` as my new column names.

I've use the following code:
`test_data.melt(ignore_index=False).groupby(['disease_state', 'disease_state_general']).apply(lambda x: x.mean(axis=1, numeric_only=True))`

this results in a long format dataframe:

[image]

Now if I use `unstack` to make a long format I get a lot of nan values. Can anyone help me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If need aggregate by `disease_state/disease_state_general` levels use:

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=['disease_state','disease_state_general'], axis=1).mean()
```